# Make file error while training YOLOv3-tiny image detection model

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolov4

So im trying to train a custom yolov4-tiny model with google colab.
At the point Makefile i get this Error Message:
Compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Makefile:162: recipe for target "obj/convolutional layer.o“ failed

make:***[obj/convolutional layer.o] Error 1

What is the problem here?

I am working in Google Colab and when updating the Make file file according to Tesla T4 GPU, it displays this error.
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
make: *** [Makefile:164: obj/convolutional_layer.o] Error 1